# Kannada text in wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, unicode, fonts, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to copy paste Kannada language content on the website from a word document.

The Published content in the front-end looks fine with the proper Kannada fonts. (I’ve used custom fonts & css).

The issue is with the back-end.

The title and content appear gibberish!

I Understand this is some kind of a encoding issue. But am not able to figure out what.

Screenshots for reference:
[image: Content]

Can someone guide me on what i am missing?

So far i have tried Database character sets & collation set to
utf8 / utf8mb4 and collation to utf8_general_ci
also,  utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Nothing worked!
Any pointers much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you pasted as TXT ?  in WP there is also a special paste function from word. If nothing else works first try to copy the test to a simple `txt` file ( to strip formatting ) and see if you can read it - and just later paste it into `wp`

Comment: Tried both copy from word, and copying into notepad before copying it again to wp. Doesn't work.

Comment: WP is (afaik) written in PHP and paired with a MySQL database? Related: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/)

Comment: @JosefZ i dint understand. are you telling me to change database charsets? which is what ive told, i have tried doing.

Comment: is that happening also in the text editor or only in visual ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Am updating this very late.

But the problem was the text encoding in the Word file.
Changing it to UTF 8, Solved it.